# How to auto resize a window when opening a program.

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm sorry if this is really basic but: when I open the Python IDLE editor, the shell opens, then I have to open the editor from the shell. Is there any way I can have the shell and editor automatically resize to a specific size upon opening? Can I use a batch file perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Options > Configure IDLE > General tab > Initial Window size